# Meteor reactive-var update one select element based on choice in other select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I have two different `select` elements in a form

[image]

When I select an option in the first list, I want a corresponding option to be automatically set in the second list. I have made a few attempts, and I am close to getting it working using `reactive-var` but I need some help.

My template looks like this

```html
<template name="inputForm">
    <div class="section">
        <form action="#">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col m4">
                    <select id="list-one">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
                        <option value="1">100</option>
                        <option value="2">75</option>
                        <option value="3">50</option>
                        <option value="4">25</option>
                        <option value="5">25</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Select List 1</label>
                </div>
                {{{secondListVar}}}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

Then in the template helper file I have

```js
var secondListVar = new ReactiveVar("<div class='input-field col m4'><select id='list-two'><option value=''  selected>Choose your option</option></select><label>Select List 2</label></div>");

Template.inputForm.helpers({
    secondListVar: function() {
        return secondListVar.get();
    }
});

Template.inputForm.events({
    'change #list-one' : function() {
        var listOneChoice = $('#list-one option:selected').text();
        switch (listOneChoice) {
            case "100":
                secondListVar.set("<div class='input-field col m4'><select id='list-two'><option value=''  selected>1.5</option></select><label>Select List 2</label></div>");
                break;
            case "75":
                break;
            case "50":
                break;
            case "25":
                break;
            case "25":
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

If I select an option from the 1st list, the 2nd list seems to get cleared

[image]

but then if I click a radio button that causes the template to be hidden/shown I get this

[image]

So I have two issues

1. The rendering doesn't seem to be dynamic, in that I need to manually force it
2. When I get the 2nd list option shown, the corresponding state of the 1st list is lost

Comment: remove your html markup from your `secondListVar`  put it in your template instead

Comment: that still doesn't change the outcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating the second list as html, and set its selection inside an autorun if you want to use a ReactiveVar.

Here's a working example : 
http://meteorpad.com/pad/JLkM8ftKQuKhBvF3r/Lists

```
<template name="Main">

      <label>Select List 1</label>
      <select id="list-one">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
          <option value="1">100</option>
          <option value="2">75</option>
          <option value="3">50</option>
          <option value="4">25</option>
          <option value="5">25</option>
      </select>


      <label>Select List 2</label>
      <select id="list-two">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
          <option value="1">100</option>
          <option value="2">75</option>
          <option value="3">50</option>
          <option value="4">25</option>
          <option value="5">25</option>
      </select>

    </template>

    var SelectedItem = new ReactiveVar();
    Template.Main.events({
        'change #list-one' : function() {
          var selected = $('#list-one option:selected').val();
          SelectedItem.set(selected);
        }
    });

    Template.Main.onCreated(function(){

      this.autorun(function(){
        var selected = SelectedItem.get();
      $('#list-two option').eq(selected).prop('selected', true);
      });

    })
```

However, you may not even need a ReactiveVar, in this case you can set the second list directly via jquery if you wanted.

Comment: I think this answer could be better if not using the global var...Why do you reject my edition?

Comment: The meteorpad link is dead. I have implemented as you have shown, but for some reason the `autorun` doesn't seem to run

Comment: If I move it from `onCreated` to `rendered` it runs, but the `$('#list-two option').eq(selected).prop('selected', true);` doesn't do anything

Comment: It is setting the option, but just not updating how it is rendered, i.e. the second list still shows `Choose your option` but if I run this in the console `$('#list-two option:selected').val();` it returns `2` or whatever option I have selected in list 1

Comment: Here is an example where it isn't working http://meteorpad.com/pad/DRm8H8iBeNuyiR3N9/Leaderboard

Comment: @robocode , I updated the meteorpad url, not sure why it was down :  http://meteorpad.com/pad/JLkM8ftKQuKhBvF3r/Lists .   In your meteorpad link, add the 'reactive-var' package and it should work.  the package is not added by default, in your app :   `$ meteor add reactive-var`

Comment: @S.Total the `SelectedItem` is file scoped since it has the "var" keyword.  If it was decared without the "var" keyword it would be global to the app.   You bring up a good point, in many cases it's better to scope vars to the template.  In this case since there is only 1 instance of our Main template, it's okay to use file scope.  Here is a good article about template scope reactive vars https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity  .   File scope vs. Template scope is subtle but very important to distinguish, perhaps you could add an additional answer showing the Template scope version?

Comment: @looshi thanks, I can see the meteorpad example working now. My example, however, is still not working. I'm wondering if the fact I'm using the `materialize` package is the problem, [example here](http://meteorpad.com/pad/ghYER8XGvXSmCuyA2/Copy%20of%20Lists)

Answer (score 0):

@looshi answer is the correct one, but I was also encountering issues due to the `materialize` package which are now sorted in [my meteorpad example](http://meteorpad.com/pad/ghYER8XGvXSmCuyA2/Copy%20of%20Lists) in light of the workaround [posted here](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1570#issuecomment-124613668)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem using Materialize.  Your form select dropdowns are being created by Materialize based on values when the page is originally rendered.  You will need to rerun the initialization code each time:

```
$('select').material_select();
```

Here's an example based on taking values from iron routers data function:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(e){
  var data = Router.current().data();

  Tracker.afterFlush(function(){
    //dom is now created.
    $('select').material_select();
  });
});
```